# AWS Topic Subscription: how do I filter on the messages to receive?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm using the java AWS SDK for the first time, using their SQS and SNS services.

I'm getting this error while trying to set a filter policy when subscribing a queue to a topic:

```
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.model.InvalidParameterException: 
Invalid parameter: FilterPolicy: "CustomerId" must be an object or an array
 at [Source: (String)"{"CustomerId": "UnitTest"}"; line: 1, column: 17]
 (Service: Sns, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 61d5c091-0502-4c10-81a0-8321b549b621, Extended Request ID: null)
```

This is my code:

```
         String subscriptionArn = response.subscriptionArn();
         String filterPolicyString = filters.toJson(); // {"CustomerId": "UnitTest"}
         SetSubscriptionAttributesRequest request = SetSubscriptionAttributesRequest.builder()
             .attributeName("FilterPolicy")
             .attributeValue(filterPolicyString)
             .subscriptionArn(subscriptionArn)
             .build();

         snsClient.setSubscriptionAttributes(request); //this is where it blows up
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the error message is self-explanatory.

Comment: how is it not already an object? what is wrong with the string {"CustomerId": "UnitTest"}?

Comment: the CustomerID needs to be an object/array like {"CustomerId": ["UnitTest"]} - I was checking out the cli command, and it looks like the following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering-apply.html

Comment: ah, I see. thanks!

Comment: @SándorBakos YAML filter policy expects a YAML sequence ( which is essentially an object/array ) but our input data which will be processed by the filter policy is a simple key-value pair mapping.  What changes should I make to the YAML filter policy so that it will only filter data based on a simple key-value pair mapping?